# Roblox Studio: Why isn't my values saving with datastore?

Tags: lua, save, game-development, roblox, datastore

i am trying to make a game and the leaderboard data should save but isn't. here is the code in serverscriptservice:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local statsDS = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("statsDS")

local SAVE_INTERVAL = 60 -- Save data every 60 seconds (1 minute)

-- Helper function to save player data
local function savePlayerData(player)
    local leaderstats = player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")

    if leaderstats then
        local Clicks = leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Clicks")
        local Time = leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Time")

        if Clicks and Time then
            local data = {Clicks.Value, Time.Value}

            local playerUserId = "Player" .. player.UserId

            local success, errorMessage = pcall(function()
                statsDS:SetAsync(playerUserId, data)
            end)

            if success then
                print("Saved data for " .. player.Name)
            else
                warn("Error saving data for " .. player.Name .. ": " .. errorMessage)
            end
        end
    end
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player

    local Clicks = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Clicks.Name = "Clicks"
    Clicks.Parent = leaderstats

    local Time = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Time.Name = "Time"
    Time.Parent = leaderstats

    local playerUserId = "Player" .. player.UserId

    local data = statsDS:GetAsync(playerUserId)

    if data then
        Clicks.Value = data[1]
        Time.Value = data[2]
    end

    player:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
    player:WaitForChild("leaderstats"):WaitForChild("Clicks")

    local lastSaveTime = tick()

    local saveTimer

    saveTimer = game:GetService("RunService").Heartbeat:Connect(function()
        if tick() - lastSaveTime >= SAVE_INTERVAL then
            lastSaveTime = tick()
            savePlayerData(player)
        end

        if not player:IsDescendantOf(game) then
            -- Player left the game
            saveTimer:Disconnect()
            savePlayerData(player)
        end
    end)
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    savePlayerData(player)
end)
```

i was expecting the data to save when i leave and rejoin, but it is reset to 0

i tried messing around with the code in every which way but nothing worked and most just made it worse.

this is a game where there is a button and you click it and it adds to the value clicks and time just shows how much time you spent in the game. the following code should save it so it works between servers but it is never working. always resets. i dont know what else to add to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that everything was client side and none of the data was being on the server. now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the game in Studio? If so by default Roblox disables Studio access to DataStores, it is only recommended to disable this security feature if your game **isn't** live. If you wish to disable this you can do so in the `Game Settings` under the `Home` tab. Otherwise, you can test the game from the Roblox Player and all DataStores should operate as intended.